# Vega visualizations for kibana - aggregations and accessing the document fields

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, kibana, vega, vega-lite

Im new to Vega and Kibana as well, Im trying to create a scatterplot showing hashtags and their average polarity, however I am stuck with two aspects, firstly geting the average polarity aggregated and secondly accessing the hashtags text field from the documents.

The code i have trying to get the average polarity (for now just showing in timescale):

```
      {$schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json
  data: {
    # URL object is a context-aware query to Elasticsearch
    url: {
      # The %-enclosed keys are handled by Kibana to modify the query
      # before it gets sent to Elasticsearch. Context is the search
      # filter as shown above the dashboard. Timefield uses the value 
      # of the time picker from the upper right corner.
      %context%: true
      %timefield%: timestamp
      index: tw
      body: {
        size: 10000
        _source: ["timestamp", "user_lang", "country", "polarity", "lang", "sentiment"]
      }
    }
    # We only need the content of hits.hits array
    format: {property: "hits.hits"}
  }
  # Parse timestamp into a javascript date value
  transform: [
    {calculate: "toDate(datum._source['timestamp'])", as: "time"}
  ]
  # Draw a circle, with x being the time field, and y - number of bytes
  mark: line
  encoding: {
    x: {field: "time", type: "temporal"}
    y: {aggregate: "mean", field: "_source.polarity", type: "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

this gives me an error Cannot read property 'polarity' of undefined. as soon as i get rid of the aggregation it works, but i want to display average not all data.

Also, I have no idea how to access the hashtag text field as its nested, i have tried _source.hashtags.text but didnt work:

example document:

```
{
        "_index": "tw",
        "_type": "tweet",
        "_id": "_HHWSGIBbYt8wc5TlB8B",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "lang": "en",
          "favorited": false,
          "sentiment": "positive",
          "user_lang": "en",
          "user_screenname": "BrideWiltshire",
          "timestamp": "2018-03-21T13:54:04.928556",
          "user_follow_count": 147,
          "hashtags": [
            {
              "indices": [
                8,
                12
              ],
              "text": "WIN"
            }
          ],
          "user_stat_count": 3377,
          "user_fav_count": 11,
          "coordinates": null,
          "source": """<a href="https://panel.socialpilot.co/" rel="nofollow">SocialPilot.co</a>""",
          "subjectivity": 0.3333333333333333,
          "user_friends_count": 62,
          "polarity": 0.5333333333333333,
          "text": "Want to #WIN ‘His and Hers’ luggage labels from @DavidHampton, worth more than £100? Enter our competition now",
          "message": "Want to #WIN ‘His and Hers’ luggage labels from @DavidHampton, worth more than £100? Enter our competition now",
          "country": null,
          "user_name": "Wiltshire Bride",
          "favorite_count": 0
        }
      },
```

mapping:

```
{
  "tw": {
    "mappings": {
      "tweet": {
        "properties": {
          "coordinates": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "country": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "favorite_count": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "favorited": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "hashtags": {
            "properties": {
              "indices": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "text": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "lang": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "location": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "message": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "polarity": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "sentiment": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "source": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "subjectivity": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "text": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "time_zone": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "user": {
            "properties": {
              "favourites_count": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "followers_count": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "friends_count": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "lang": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "screen_name": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "statuses_count": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "user_fav_count": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "user_follow_count": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "user_friends_count": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "user_lang": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "user_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "user_screenname": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "user_stat_count": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to reproduce and your example seems to behave properly for me.  What does [`VEGA_DEBUG.view.data('source_0')`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/vega-browser-debugging-console.html) provide?

Comment: ive tried to use the debugging tool,@StevenEnsslen but i find it confusing as Kibana shows an error however the tool does not seem to help with it, this is what im getting when running the original code from the question: ` VEGA_DEBUG.view.data('source_0')
(2491) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},…]`
vendors.bundle.js?v=16588:58 XHR finished loading: POST "http://x.x.x.x:5601/elasticsearch/tw/_search".`

Comment: That is standard behavior for large arrays in the developer console, @Angelika. Though I've given up trying to find a reference for it.  If you expand the individual ranges you should see your objects.  They should be formatted like `0: Object { timestamp:"2018-03-21T13:54:04.928556", user_lang:"en",  polarity: 0.5333333333333333, lang:"en", sentiment:"positive"}`  The usual problem is that the `format` is incomplete or the columns have different names, in my experience both usually typing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your hashtags field is a nested type and hashtags.text is a keyword field(or has hashtags.text.keyword) then you can scatterplot with the following

```
{
  $schema: https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v2.json
  title: hashtags vs avg_polarity
  data: {
    url: {
      index: twitter
      body: {
        size: 0
        query: {
          match_all: {}
        }
        aggs: {
          HashTags: {
            nested: {path: "hashtags"}
            aggs: {
              HashTags_Text: {
                terms: {field: "hashtags.text"}
                aggs: {
                  Tweet_Polarity: {
                    reverse_nested: {}
                    aggs: {
                      Tweet_Polarity_avg: {
                        avg: {field: "polarity"}
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    format: {property: "aggregations.HashTags.HashTags_Text.buckets"}
  }
  mark: {type: "line"}
  encoding: {
    x: {
      field: key
      type: Nominal
      axis: {title: "HashTags"}
    }
    y: {
      field: Tweet_Polarity.Tweet_Polarity_avg.value
      type: quantitative
      axis: {title: "polarity"}
    }
  }
}
```

Little illustration for fun
[image]
**EDIT**

You will have to specify your index mapping as below before you start adding docs

```
POST /tw
{
"mappings": {
            "tweet": {
                "properties": {
                    "favorite_count": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "favorited": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "hashtags": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "indices": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "text": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "lang": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "message": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "polarity": {
                        "type": "float"
                    },
                    "sentiment": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "source": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "subjectivity": {
                        "type": "float"
                    },
                    "text": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "timestamp": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "user_fav_count": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "user_follow_count": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "user_friends_count": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "user_lang": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "user_name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "user_screenname": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "user_stat_count": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Change the mark type to circle from line for actual scatter

Comment: thank you for your reply @sramalingam24, I have tried the code above and im getting the [aggregation_execution_exception] [nested] nested path [hashtags] is not nested error? could the reason be that some documents have no hashtags?

Comment: Seems like the hashtags field in your tweet type is not mapped as nested type. You will have to explicitly specify it when you create the tw index and set the mapping on tweet type.

Comment: oh, so i wouldnt be able to do it as i already have around 10mln documents in that index, i believe i would have to start fresh index as im aware its not possible to update the index mapping?

Comment: also, tried just to display average polarity from your code @sramalingam24 (ive deleted the hashtags part) and im getting this error: [search_parse_exception] Reverse nested aggregation [Tweet_Polarity] can only be used inside a [nested] aggregation, ive updated my question to display my current mapping

Comment: @Angelika You can use the _reindex api to copy your documents into a new index with the above mapping or you can add a copy of the hashtags field (call it hashtags_copy) with nested mapping applied to the copied field using _update_by_query api. As far as the query not working you will need nested mapping for the reverse_nested query to work